# DelphiPrism XE - strategies on migrating to .NET Framework 4.0 (4.8 really)

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, delphi-prism, oxygene

Maybe this isn't a strict programming question, but i'm working on an old project using DelphiPrism XE.

We have a large system in that Oxygene environment that cannot be simply rewritten.

Tools like dotPeek might work on some level, as with the generated .dll we're able to "convert back" (at some level) to straight C# (one thing of notice is that constants are written as their values, propably due to compiler optimizations).

We're considering any strategy at this point, that doesn't involve a large human refactor. Anything AI or using a conversion tool would work wonders.

A curious fact is that we reached out Embarcadero and they doesn't sell licenses for this IDE anymore - at least that was their answer when we reached them. Some new developers cannot join this effort as we're running out of active licenses.

Any help is appreciated. There aren't many references online, that I found, that could discuss what can be done here in the current year.

Comment: You contact the wrong side. https://www.remobjects.com/elements/oxygene/prism.aspx In short, you need to become a RemObjects customer now.

Comment: @LexLi let my manager know that, thanks!